# Reporting confidence interval of linear mixed model in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, confidence-interval

Hi I have a question regarding interpreting the confidence interval of linear mixed model in R

So I have a model like this

```
a2 <- lmer(RT ~ Trial + (1 + Trial | ID), data = d2)

summary(a2)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: RT ~ Trial + (1 + Trial | ID)
   Data: d2

REML criterion at convergence: 21952.6

Scaled residuals: 

    Min      1Q    Median      3Q     Max 
-6.5799   -0.4538  -0.0546  0.4154  5.6741 

Random effects:

 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 ID       (Intercept)  3.780   1.944         
          Trial        2.928   1.711    -0.20
 Residual             18.938   4.352         
Number of obs: 3701, groups:  ID, 205

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   3.4625     0.1542  22.450
Trial         0.3462     0.1426   2.427

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
      (Intr)
Trial -0.145
```

And then i calculate the confidence interval

```
> confint(a2, oldNames = FALSE)
Computing profile confidence intervals ...
                               2.5 %      97.5 %
sd_(Intercept)|ID         1.70924477  2.19902280
cor_Trial.(Intercept)|ID -0.37359403 -0.01528644
sd_Trial|ID               1.48596866  1.95348922
sigma                     4.24882612  4.45891618
(Intercept)               3.15960363  3.76556626
Trial                     0.06594692  0.62636130
```

I'm not sure what each row in the confidence interval represents. When asked to report the confidence interval of Trial I thought it was (0.07, 0.63) but turns out it should be (1.49, 1.95). Why is that ?

Comment: Take out the 1+ in your random effect in a2 and see what happens.

Comment: how did it 'turn out' to be the other? Each means something different so be very explicit about what you are being asked to report.

Comment: I got asked the question : what is the random effect SD and confidence interval, based on profile likelihood (the default), for Trial? And I answered with (0.07, 0.63) but the correct answer is (1.49, 1.95)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `Trial` is a dichotomous variable taking values 0 and 1, then

- The 95% confidence interval for `Trial` (0.07 - 0.63) is for the difference of the average `RT` between `Trial=1` and `Trial=0`.
- The 95% confidence interval for `sd_Trial|ID` (1.49 - 1.95) is for the standard deviation of the random subject-specific differences between `Trial=1` and `Trial=0`.